# extending an image with Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to increase the height of an image using PIL but I don't want the image to be resized; I actually want a strip of blank pixels at the bottom of the image. Any way of doing this with PIL?
I guess one way would be to make a new image of the required size and copy the old image into it but I can't seem to find the right function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, just realized you can do image.crop() and it will resize the image for you.